# New York Times API through the command line

Tags: api, command-line, text-analysis

I'm using the command line to tap into the New York Times API and running into issues. I get the `'http' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file` when I run        http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?[q=obama]&api-key=(my key)'

Any help would bee appreciated.

Comment: URLs are not command line applications.. you can't just "run" a URL. The closest equivalent to what you're trying to do is to use something like [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) where you can then run `curl http://api.nytimes.com/...`

Answer (score 2):

Simply typing URLs doesn't work on Linux. You must use `curl`. For retrieving JSON from a GET request with `curl`:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=obama&api-key=KEY
```

Best regards,